# grammar question - use of word "munch"

Tags: grammar

I munch my food

- is this sentence correct? or should I change it to "I munch on my food"?

Comment: Have you tried googling it or looking in dictionaries? If so, tell us what you found and why you're still not sure how to use "munch". If not, please do that first before asking questions here. Tx!

Answer (score 0):

Both have usage.  This can be checked with a search engine

- [I munch my food](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+munch+on+my+food%22)
- [I munch on my food](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+munch+on+my+food%22)

You would be unlikely to use either as a simple present sentence.  But they could appear in a subordinate clause

> John continues to talk about work as I munch (on) my food.